# Xamarin.Mac Deployment issue

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I am trying to deploy and debug a xamarin.mac app inside a xamarin.forms application. I can build it but am not able to deploy it to my mac. (I am using VS for mac) the error pop up is not helpful either as the link supplied leaves me at a 404 page.
No one else in my team has this issue and build configurations and settings are the same.

Error message

Unable to launch application to debug, possibly due to it crashing quickly.
See https://aka.ms/xm-crash-no-output for more help.

Could not open /Users/sam/myapp: pid returned -1

Comment: Have you made sure you've followed all of the steps in the [Platform Setup Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/mac), have you checked your linker settings & made sure you aren't linking any code? Can you create and launch a hello world xamarin forms app on macOS successfully?

Comment: Hello, Yes I have been able to deploy a hello world app and have previously been able to build this app too, but after switching to a new mac I have not been able to. My linker settings are the same I believe as others in my team